# complex json data array in array in static tableview (for detail)

Tags: arrays, swift

```
import UIKit

struct Base : Codable {
    let genres : [Genres]?
    let name : String?
    let overview : String?
}

struct Genres : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
}

func fillSelectedShowDetails() {
    let selectedURL = URL(string: " ")

    guard let downloadedURL = selectedURL else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadedURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("something went wrong in selectedURL")
            return
        }
        print("Downloaded selectedURL")
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedResults = try decoder.decode(Base.self, from: data)
            self.detailedTV = decodedResults

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showNameLabel.text = decodedResults.name
                self.overwievLabel.text = decodedResults.overview
                if self.detailedTV?.genres?.count == 2 {
                    self.genreLabel.text = decodedResults.genres?[1].name
                } else {
                    self.genreLabel.text = decodedResults.genres?[0].name
                }

                print(decodedResults.genres)
            }
        } catch {
            print("something wrong after downloaded in selectedURL\(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I need every genre name and write it to text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create a single string from all of the values for the `name` property then use `map` and `joined`:

```
let genreNames = decodedResults.genres?.compactMap { $0.name }.joined(separator: ",") ?? """
self.genreLabel.text = genreNames
```

Comment: i already tried that but getting Value of type '[Genres]' has no member 'name' error

Comment: I didn't notice that both `genres` and `name` are optional. I've updated the answer to properly deal with the optionals.